# What entry should be made in Android Manifest file when creating DBAdapter or a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-manifest

I have created DBAdapter but what entry should I make in the android manifest file??
And for my other app I am using a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper..what entry should I make in the manifest file for that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless any of those are also extending `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`, you don't even have to mention them in the manifest.  Treat them like regular Java classes.